# Is this a good practice to create a big holdall table?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-performance

I'm at an internship in an enterprise where I make select queries on a SQL Oracle database and I want to take a step back to be sure what is a good practice or not to keep from this.

They made a table with different types of code like :

```
ID       |  TYPE       | Code       |
-------------------------------------
1        |   1         | red        |
2        |   1         | white      |
3        |   1         | blue       |
4        |   1         | green      |
5        |   2         | dept1      |
6        |   2         | dept2      |
7        |   2         | dept3      |
8        |   3         | prodtype1  |
9        |   3         | prodtype2  |
10       |   3         | prodtype3  |
```

As you see, there is few information for each of the code. Is this a valid practice to regroup little tables with few information in a big one, and retrieve our information while selecting by a WHERE clause on the column "type" ?
At my scale, I would have to create three tables (color, department, productiontype) but there is very few information. Does it cost a lot of resources to keep three little tables? Does it lead to huge problems at long term to use a big table with different "kind" of information in it?

Comment: They appear to be simple textual lookups. Separate tables for each lookup has advantages and disadvantages. There is no clear "best" option.

Comment: Can you list some of the advantages and the drawbacks of this kind of practice ? Because I find it clearer to keep separate tables, but it can also make the relational model heavy for no benefits no ?

Comment: This (anti-) pattern is generally referred to as OTLT (One True Lookup Table). The major disadvantage, IMO, is that unless you employ wider foreign key constraints, there's nothing to stop someone storing e.g. `prodtype2`, a.k.a `9` in a column expecting a color. I.e. to get decent integrity, the FK has to cover the `type` column as well as the `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use both key/value tables and multiple tables. It depends on what you need.

For example, you have a "dept1". Do you want to save more information regarding your departments? Then it makes sense to create a new table "Department" with its location and make a foreign key to this new table.

As for performance, both should work OK as long as your indexes are correct.

Comment: Information in the table is just used to print on some reports and there is no more information required about each of the code.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned earlier this is an entity-attribute-value pattern which is generally regarded as an anti-pattern.  The wittiest denouncement of it can be read at https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/when-the-fever-is-over-and-ones-work-is-done/

One True Lookup designs have trouble enforcing referential integrity either in entirety or without adding huge complexity.

The design represents a database within a database, sometimes called the inner system effect.

There are specific and limited use cases or situations where an EAV model is useful.  These tend to be in cases where the attributes of an entity can be incredibly free form.

- A large number of data classes with very little in common in terms of their attributes.
- A small number of attributes per object.
- Fluid business requirements or difficulty pinning down data requirements making traditional data modelling difficult or impractical.
- Rate of change within an entity is low being limited to inserts and deletes.
- Interaction with objects in the model is largely at the entity level, that is the entire entity is retrieved, little if any filtering is performed at the attribute level.

Systems where it works are

- Surveys and questionnaires
- Product review systems
- Application config systems
- Medical systems

These days I would question whether an RDBMS is the correct solution for these use cases anyway.  A NOSQL solution such as a document store is a closer match for the use cases mentioned above.